# SQL conditional data copy tableB to new column in existing tableA

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, conditional-statements, sql-update

I am struggling with transferring data in SQL to a new column (which is not difficult, cause I am quite inexperienced in SQL XD). I'll try to describe the problem:

```
I need to transfer some data using UPDATE statement from existing tableB.potatoes to 
new created column potatoes_new in existing tableA (tableB.potatoes -> tableA.potatoes_new

Conditions:
-tableB has foreign key tableB.tableA_ID referencing tableA.ID
-tableB.potatoes and tableB.tableA_ID are not unique but in registers with same tableA_ID, potatos is also the same:
example:
tableB                         tableA
ID   tableA_ID   potatoes      ID    potatoes_new(current)   potatoes_new(desired)
1    1           105           1     NULL                    105
2    1           105           2     NULL                    51
3    2           51            3     NULL                    33
4    3           33
5    3           33
6    3           33


It is not necessary to delete the data from tableB.columnA, just copy to the RIGHT register:
-> where tableA.ID = tableB.tableA_ID
```

I searched for some time but did not found what I want (or at least I did not understand how those solutions could solve my problem...)

PS: This is my first post...sorry for the format, I tried for some time bit did not managed better. If you have some hints or links...I would appreciate it

EDIT: Solution (after GabrielVal helped me with his answer)

```
Changes I had to do to GabrielVal answer:
1. I had to substitute the tableB to a  as the MERGE statement was having problems finding several records in tableB in which tableB.tableA_ID = tableA.ID
2. Thus I deleted the INSERT INTO WHEN NOT MATCHED because I did not want to create new records on tableA, but just fill the current ones
MERGE dbo.tableA as [target]
USING  (SELECT DISTINCT tableA_ID,potatoes_new FROM tableB WHERE Measurement_ID != 0 ) as [source]
ON  [source].tableA_ID = [target].ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET  [target].SystemID = [source].System_ID;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need a merge statement here, something like this?

```
MERGE dbo.tableA as TARGET
USING  dbo.tableB as SOURCE
ON  SOURCE.tableA_id = Target.id 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET  target.id = source.tableA_id,
target.potatoes_new = source.potatoes, 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT ( ID, tableA_id, potatoes )
VALUES (Source.ID, Source.potatoes_new);
```

Comment: thank you. Your help was very useful. I made some changes and it worked.

Comment: Thanks! Be sure to click the up arrow next to my answer please. Cheers